# How to change ownership for the directory on the mounted disk?

Tags: mount, partition, chown

The disk partition `/dev/sda7` was mounted on `/media/debian/8eda3aeb-e21b-455f-bb7a-f46005fb4893`,i want to change ownership for the directory `/media/debian/8eda3aeb-e21b-455f-bb7a-f46005fb4893/mydoc`,

```
sudo chown -R  debian:debian /media/debian/8eda3aeb-e21b-455f-bb7a-f46005fb4893/mydoc
```

It encounter an issue such as below:

```
chown: changing ownership of '/media/debian/8eda3aeb-e21b-455f-bb7a-f46005fb4893/mydoc': Operation not permitted
```

How to fix it ?
Display uuid and file type:

```
sudo blkid |grep sda7
/dev/sda7: UUID="B8DC-0104" TYPE="vfat" PARTLABEL="win10" PARTUUID="cdbdb58a-158d-428b-b572-5d4a2ad391c9"
```

Mount this way,

```
cat /etc/fstab
UUID=B8DC-0104    /media/debian/8eda3aeb-e21b-455f-bb7a-f46005fb4893  vfat  rw,user,exec,umask=000 0 0
```

Try as @waltinator say in
[mount fat](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1113469/cant-write-on-fat32-partition-although-having-rw-mount-option/1113550#1113550)

step1: remove setting on /etc/fstab,delete the following line

```
UUID=B8DC-0104    /media/debian/8eda3aeb-e21b-455f-bb7a-f46005fb4893  vfat  rw,user,exec,umask=000 0 0
```

step2:reboot
step3:

```
target=/dev/sda7
mntdir=/mnt/wordpress
sudo mkdir mntdir
sudo mount -t vfat -o remount,rw,user,users,nosuid,nodev,relatime,uid=$(id -u),gid=$(id -g),fmask=0022,dmask=0022,codepage=437,iocharset=iso8859-1,shortname=mixed,showexec,utf8,flush,errors=remount-ro,uhelper=udisks2 $target $mntdir
```

An error info:

```
mount: /mnt/wordpress not mounted or bad option

       In some cases useful info is found in syslog - try
       dmesg | tail or so.
```

Show dmesg

```
sudo dmesg|tail
[   39.748493] ashmem: initialized
[   46.748313] NET: Registered protocol family 3
[   46.958169] NET: Registered protocol family 5
[   48.384024] audit: type=1400 audit(1596700794.077:36): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" profile="unconfined" name="docker-default" pid=1476 comm="apparmor_parser"
[   50.467394] audit: type=1326 audit(1596700796.161:37): auid=4294967295 uid=0 gid=0 ses=4294967295 subj==unconfined pid=780 comm="anbox" exe="/snap/anbox/186/usr/bin/anbox" sig=0 arch=c000003e syscall=165 compat=0 ip=0x7fab12334c5a code=0x7ffc0000
[   50.769984] audit: type=1326 audit(1596700796.461:38): auid=4294967295 uid=0 gid=0 ses=4294967295 subj==unconfined pid=780 comm="anbox" exe="/snap/anbox/186/usr/bin/anbox" sig=0 arch=c000003e syscall=165 compat=0 ip=0x7fab12334c5a code=0x7ffc0000
[   51.179790] audit: type=1326 audit(1596700796.873:39): auid=4294967295 uid=0 gid=0 ses=4294967295 subj==unconfined pid=780 comm="anbox" exe="/snap/anbox/186/usr/bin/anbox" sig=0 arch=c000003e syscall=165 compat=0 ip=0x7fab12334c5a code=0x7ffc0000
[   54.041691] Bridge firewalling registered
[   54.212587] Initializing XFRM netlink socket
[   54.368677] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): docker0: link is not ready
```

Comment: Which filesystem? Mounted how?

Comment: You cannot change Linux ownership & permissions on Windows formats like FAT32 & NTFS. It just not supported. You get the defaults from how you mount it. https://askubuntu.com/questions/22215/why-have-both-mnt-and-media  Also best not to use FAT32 for larger partitions. It does not allow files larger than 4GB and has no journal so repair may be difficult or impossible.  Often better to label partitions, so mounted with label, not UUID. Or create your own mount and use that. Label or mount like "Music", "Docs" or similar is more informative than UUID or Windows drive letter.

Comment: If it's fat32, you need to set ownership and group as part of the mount options: https://askubuntu.com/a/1113550/158442

Answer (score -2):

Since `sudo` is not working, run `su`, enter the root password, and run `chown -R  debian:debian /media/debian/8eda3aeb-e21b-455f-bb7a-f46005fb4893/mydoc`. Ought to work.